# Cannot enable FileVault (options greyed out) on macOS Catalina Clean install

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, filevault, system-settings

I just did a clean install off my MacBook Pro by `dd`'ing the hard drive and then installing macOS Catalina from a bootable USB. I formatted the internal SSD using the Apple filesystem and installed it successfully. Now, when trying to enable FileVault via **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **FileVault** > **Turn on FileVault**, I get a pop-up with both the "Set up my iCloud account to reset my password" and "Create a recovery key and do not use my iCloud account" options greyed out. The "Back" and "Continue" buttons are also greyed out. The only button that is not greyed out is the "Cancel" button. So essentially, I can not enable FileVault via the system preferences pane. See the screenshot below.

What in the world is happening, and how do I fix this so that I can enable FileVault via the System Preferences pane again?

[image: Cannot Enable FileVault from System Preferences macOS Catalina]

**Update:**

Hardware Info:

MacBook Pro 11,3 15" 2014 running macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

The internal SSD is the one that came with the MacBook Pro and is unmodified.

The SSD is formatted with a GUID partition map and an APFS filesystem.

**Other hardware notes:**

I bought a second official OEM Apple Samsung SSD on eBay of the exact same type with the exact same model number. Installed it, along with a new macOS, and the same problem occurred on a completely different OEM SSD.

**Attempts to Remedy and Solve:**

So far, here are the things that I have done and the outcomes from them:

1. I have tried enabling it through the command line and according to the command line utility, it successfully encrypts itself.

   - the outcome is that even though the command line utility says it is encrypted, the System Preferences stays the same and does **not** acknowledge any sort of encryption.
2. Clean installed macOS Catalina from a bootable Catalina USB drive **after** formatting my Mac drive with Disk Utility.

   - the outcome is that the exact same problem occurred. Nothing has changed.
3. Clean installed macOS Catalina from a bootable USB drive **after** `dd`'ing the entire drive from the terminal in the macOS bootable USB.

   - the outcome is that the exact same problem occurred. Nothing has changed.
4. Booted from a "Parted Magic" live USB and used `gdisk` to erase not only the GPT partition map but also the MBR (or PMBR) maps. Following this, I also did a secure-erase (after unfreezing
   the drive from sleep in order to unlock it), with Parted Magic's built-in disk erase utility, as well as another erase of the GPT and PMBR partition maps using Parted Magic's built-in disk erase utility.

   - the outcome was a zeroed internal Mac SSD.
5. Afterward, I once again, booted up a macOS bootable USB drive, formatted it with disk utility (GPT partition map w/ Apple filesystem), and did a clean install of macOS again from USB.

   - the outcome is that the same problem occurred.
6. Did steps 1-5 using macOS Internet Recovery instead of using a bootable USB.

   - the outcome is that the same problem occurred in all cases
7. Removed original Mac SSD, and installed 2nd OEM Mac SSD purchased from eBay. Then did a clean install from Internet Recovery.

   - The outcome is that the same problem occurred.
8. Before and after steps 1-7, I ran the Apple Hardware Test both from the internal drive, as well as the Internet Hardware Test.

   - the outcome is that no hardware was considered faulty, and all hardware was properly working.
9. Fixed but not solved:
   After doing a final clean install, with Internet Recovery on the new SSD, I once again tried encrypting from the command line utility. Before the command line utility could start actually encrypting itself, I once again booted from Internet Recovery,
   `dd`'d the drive, and again did a clean install.

   - outcome, the issue has resolved itself in the oddest way. After zeroing the disk before the command line utility could finish encrypting the drive, and then doing a clean install from internet recovery, the problem no longer appeared.

**Special notes/hints that could possibly identify the problem:**

1. the only real thing that I can think of that could have somehow caused this is that one time when I was in the
   macOS recovery drive using the terminal, I accidentally `dd`'s (using `/dev/zero`) one of the supposedly read-only
   memory partitions (I believe those partitions start at /dev/disk3 or `/dev/disk4` and go to `/dev/disk13` or higher,
   depending on the OS of the recovery partition you loaded).

As far as I can remember, I have never been able to modify those extra ramdisk partitions that appear in the macOS
recovery volume (or internet recovery/bootable USB for that matter), and they have always appeared as read-only.

So how I was able to successfully `dd` one of those partitions (on accident of course) is beyond me.

This is the only possible info that I can imagine might somehow be the culprit in affecting multiple clean installs
across multiple hard drives, by preventing the system preferences panel from enabling FileVault.

Weird!

**Summary & Final Statement:**
I suggest leaving this post up because it is definitely different than any other post when you get into specifics, as well
as the fact that this occurred on two different hard drives. Which tells me it is some sort of hardware issue, or possibly,
a rootkit, or some sort of other billion-dollar virus. But most likely some odd hardware problem that is undetected by Apple.

**Don't delete this, It still needs a proper solution:**
Although the issue is no longer happening, I don't believe a proper solution or **reason** as to why this occurred, or how
it was solved and has been mentioned. So I would definitely recommend this post being left up because I can almost 100%
guarantee that this will happen to me again, as I am the king of having weird Mac problems that Google and Stack forums
have absolutely zero mention of it.

Any thoughts?

DEC. 31, 2020 Update:

I once again `dd`'d my hard drive, as well as did an erase using the hard drive's firmware from Linux using `hdparm`. Then, I formatted it with a bootable macOS USB installer again and reinstalled it. The same issue appeared.

I tried the suggested commands in the below answers and got the following output:
`MacBook-Pro:~ dan$ sysadminctl -secureTokenStatus dan sysadminctl[45304:702359] Secure token is ENABLED for user dan sysadminctl interactive -secureTokenStatus dan Secure token is ENABLED for user dan sysadminctl -secureTokenOn dan -password sysadminctl[32917:677328] Operation is not permitted without secure token unlock. MacBook-Pro:~ dan$ sysadminctl -secureTokenOn dan -password - sysadminctl[51227:713574] Operation is not permitted without secure token unlock. MacBook-Pro:~ dan$ sudo sysadminctl -secureTokenOn dan -password - Password: sysadminctl[51218:713260] Operation is not permitted without secure token unlock.`

So it seems, that my secure token is enabled, and working, which eliminates the securetoken assumption being the problem.

Finally I ran
`sudo fdesetup enable -user dan`
in which FileVault seemed to start encrypting my drive from the terminal.
After the encryption was finished, System Preferences now looked normal in the security pane stating "FileVault is turned on for the disk "MacHD". The option to turn off FileVault from System Preferences seems fully functional. I have not tried disabling and then reenabling from System Preferences again yet.

Comment: Can you provide more details concerning your disk? Is it GUID, MBR and HFS or AFS? What is the exact model you are using? Was it modified?

Comment: I'm tentatively voting to close as a duplicate of [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313366/what-is-a-secure-token-and-how-do-i-get-an-admin-users-that-has-one), since I'm fairly sure that it's the same situation; however, I'm happy to revoke that if it's not the case. By the way, have you tried enabling it through the command line?

Comment: You are right @JMY1000 but there are a lot of answers to wade through over there. I’m going to try to make a new answers that combines the best of the other thread and hopefully can be clearer for someone just coming at this from a GUI perspective and not wanting to use the command line. Great question on a very convoluted issue.

Comment: @JMY1000 Please dont close this. I will update with much more info in a few days when i have free time.

Comment: @DanRan  bmike says open, so it shall be

Comment: @bmike Thanks a ton for letting this stay open. It is definitely a similar issue, but per the debugging and steps that I've added in my update, i strongly do not think its the same issue. Also, serious appologies for not updating this right away. I got swamped in life and couldnt take care of it til now.  UPDATED NOW THOUGH! Thanks!

Comment: @JMY1000, as i stated with bmike you are right that both issues have similarities, but check my update, because with the specifics that I have added, I believe these are most definitely two seperate issues. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

As you have already got an answer for most of this question, I've got an answer for a smaller part of it:

You were surprised by the fact that you can "dd" a read-only partition and wonder why that is. I need to clarify that when you write "dd", I assume you mean that you've used the `dd` command to overwrite the drive with zeroes or random data. `dd` has many other uses, so just to clarify that part.

The reason why it is actually unsurprising is that you have invoked `dd` to do work on *drives* in contrast to working on files in a *file system*:

When you've listed the mounted volumes, you were actually looking at mounted file systems. File systems can easily be mounted read-only and will appear as such. It is at the file system level that this restriction occurs.

However when you're accessing disks directly, you're entirely bypassing any file system - and thus any read-only mount is not restricting you. This means that it is fully possible to overwrite or trash a read-only file systems, and it is also possible to do so while they're mounted - however that can lead to very unfortunate things happening (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

We have to remediate this at work from time to time. This answer linked below is the best for me to use (and the others in the linked question are good, but not great for my needs). With enough care and patience, you can almost always fix this without an “Apple direct” erase install.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313780/5472

> To manually grant a secure token, run

```
sysadminctl -secureTokenOn yourusername -password -
```

> where yourusername is the username of the user you wish to grant a secure token to. Don't forget the hyphen at the end too! Don't use sudo.

This can fail, and then you want to back up and erase and start over being sure you make a good admin account with a throw away admin user. Only when you’re sure your OS install has a secure token, then run Migration Assistant to reload your apps, settings, actual user data and accounts.

When I say “erase and start over” I mean you want to use internet recovery to do the erase and the install so the erase is clean and the installer downloads from Apple direct - completely fresh and updated.

---

*n.b. This is one of the more bizarre and hard things most mac admins do. Super finicky processes and many different scenarios involved. Luckily with T2 chip Macs, this is far less likely to happen. Fingers crossed it can’t happen with the new M1 hardware ever again.*

Some of the story on this journey is told well by Rich Trouton

- https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2019/02/08/unable-to-enable-filevault-on-macos-mojave/ (a much longer workaround that uses the macOS Recovery **resetFileVaultpassword** tool)
- https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2019/02/10/re-syncing-local-account-passwords-and-secure-token-on-filevault-encrypted-macs-running-macos-mojave/ (workaround if you have a personal recovery key handy)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117317/discussion-on-answer-by-bmike-cannot-enable-filevault-options-greyed-out-on-ma).